# extract column values based on another column

Tags: python

I have two columns such as this:

> wind    play
>
> yes    no
>
> no    yes
>
> no    no
>
> yes    yes

If the value in the `wind` column is `yes`, I want to extract the corresponding values in the `play` column irrespective of whether the value in that column is `yes` or `no`.

I wrote this `for` loop to do this but, I am not sure if this is the right way to do such an operation? `tar_attr_labels` is the `play` column.

```
for val in labelFreq.keys():         # dict contains yes and no

    dataSubset = [entry for entry in tar_attr_labels if val]
    .....
```

Comment: `column` isn't a Python object type.  What does your data structure look like?  Do you have a list of lists?  Two dictionaries?  Etc.

Comment: ...or a file that you are reading?

Comment: Can you `print` `labelFreq`? Or the output of `labelFreq.items()[:5]`?

Comment: @DSM My file is a .csv file. I zipped it in such a way using the `*` operator so that I have all the columns of file stored in separate variables. `labelFreq` is just a dictionary that stores the count of the two values `yes` and `no`. If I print it, then I will get the number of times `yes` or `no` has appeared in the column.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `labelFreq` variable has a dictionary with your `wind` column as key and `play` column as value.

If this is true, here is what you want to do:

```
data_subset = {wind: play for wind, play in labelFreq.items() if wind == 'yes'}
```

Comment: Not really, no. `labelFreq` just contains the count of the words `yes` and `no` in the `wind` column. Based on whether `wind` is `yes` (or no), I want to extract the corresponding values from `play` irrespective of whether `play` is `yes` or `no`

Comment: You can create a dictionary the way I suggested, just applying `dict()` to your data, instead of `zip()`.

Comment: The syntax for dict comprehension uses `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: @iurisilvio How do I create a dictionary with `wind` as the key and play as the `value`?

Comment: The reason is because the two columns are stored in two separate variables.

Comment: @Eagle show me all your code, I don't know what you already did.

Comment: @iurisilvio Uh oh, I changed the whole implementation because it wasn't working. :/ I did away with the whole column thing and I am working on rows now. My implementation is now close to what has been  done in this webpage: https://github.com/NinjaSteph/DecisionTree/blob/master/src/DecisionTree.py

Comment: I have no idea how to relate with this code, but you can create my `labelFreq` with `dict(data)`, where `data` is like the one in that `majority` function.

Comment: @iurisilvio Right, that's exactly what I am doing :)